# retrieve data for grid/chart from httpwebrequest call to url

Tags: ajax, extjs, grid, httpwebrequest

I am trying to get a grid filled with the json response I would receive when making a httpwebrequest call to a url endpoint which requires authentication. The data will be in json form:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "value": "(\"Samsung Health\")",
        "tag": "ME"
    },
    {
        "value": "(\"Samsung Galaxy Tab\")",
        "tag": "HIM"
    },
    {
        "value": "(\"Amazon fire\")",
        "tag": "ME"
    }
]
```

}

I am not sure how to even start and whether to use Ext.Ajax.Request or some type of call from code behind. I am using vb.net in code behind. Any suggestions appreciated. Sample code for ajax call;

```
  function getMembers() {

    var parameters = {
        node: dynamicNodeId
    }

    Ext.Ajax.Request({
        url: 'https://data.json',
        method: 'GET',
        jsonData: Ext.encode(parameters),
        success: function (response, opts) {
            alert('I WORKED!');
            //decode json string
            var responseData = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

            //Load store from here
            memberStore.loadData(responseData);
        },
        failure: function (response, opts) {
            alert('I DID NOT WORK!');
        }

    });

}
```

The grid formation:

```
 var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    stateful: true,
    stateId: 'stateGrid',
    columns: [
        {
            text: 'Query',
            flex: 1,
            sortable: false,
            dataIndex: 'query'
        },
        {
            text: 'Last Updated',
            width: 85,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
            dataIndex: 'lastChange'
        },
```

Here query would be the value from the json response and lastChange the current datetime. I tried the proxy request call and realized that since I am calling an endpoint on a different domain I needed to use jsonp.

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     model: 'User',
     proxy: {
         type: 'jsonp',
         extraParams: {
            login: 'username',
            password: 'password'
         },
         url: 'https://api.data/rules.json',
         reader: {
             type: 'json',
             root: 'rules'
         },
         callbackParam: 'callback'
     },
     autoLoad: true
 });
```

I might have to just figure out some other way to do by making sure all the data I needed is called to a database by some other function.

Comment: In your json example the code is not surrounded by a `callback` parameter.  Does your service return the data surrounded by `callback`? If you are needing `jsonp` for `same-origin` constraint then this would be necessary and would cause issues when the `reader` tries to parse.

Comment: It is not a service call per say but a call to an api endpoint and I do not see it surrounded by callback

Comment: To use `jsonp` it will have to return in `callback` so that it can be parsed correctly, otherwise the `reader` will through an exception because the `callback` doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks. I think I am going to put all the data that I need into a mongodb collection and then call the data from there. Thanks for your help. By the way, do you know what the performance difference would be for jsonp calls vs mongo

Comment: You can't really compare `jsonp` and mongo, `jsonp` is a way to "serve" data cross domain (really more of a hack using script tags) and mongodb is storage.  I think even with mongodb you would have to serve the data through use of a web service (node.js,wcf,etc)?

Comment: Thanks for your continued helpful comments. I looked into node.js to incorporate with mongodb and just finished some basic tutorials. I just want to confirm my understanding if you don't mind: the node.js will basically create the 'webservices' I need to call from extjs to populate my widgets correct? so if I have a http://localhost:3000/helloworld returning a string, I could use this string to populate a grid?

Comment: Just wanted to add, that I find it hard to read and understand books etc to learn new technology and always find it helpful when people comment and give directions and not negative votes

Comment: Your logic is correct. However, ExtJS is built to handle json really well.  So instead of just returning a string response you should return the string wrapped in json.  There should be examples on the tubes regarding node.js returning json.

Comment: Sorry tubes? you mean youtube?

Comment: yes, youtube possibly, but i meant the internet in general. Here is an [example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5KwFQOXrY4) from sencha regarding node.js rest api. Can't say how good it is haven't watched. But my point is that there are already examples out there.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for your situation would be to create store that is configured with a remote proxy. See the example at the top of this documentation page: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

The remote proxy will take care of the AJAX request to retrieve the data, and the store will automatically manage casting the data results to Ext.data.Model instances. Once the store is loaded with data, the grid to which the store is bound will also automatically handle rendering the data that has been populated into the store.

Comment: could you take a look at the EDIT above